# picklist values are available even without giving access to it in Record type

Tags: picklist, record-type

There are already 2 pick list values "Yes" and "No" for a field "F1" in the Object "xyz". There are two record types A and B. Record type A alone have access to these 2 fields. Now i created a picklist value "N/A" for the field F1 and gave access in Record type A alone. But i am able to see all the picklist values including "N/A" in the field for the record type B also. There are other record types also in addition to A and B. they have access to "Yes" and "No" picklist values but not to "N/A". but there it is working fine. I'm able to see only "Yes" and "No" but not the "N/A" for the field F1. Only in record type B even if there is no access for any of the picklist values all the values are visible. please let me know what might be the cause for it.

Comment: Is it dependent picklist?

Comment: @RahulSharma No, it is not.

Comment: Bro did you check B record type as it may have access for the picklist value N/A

Comment: @prasanthcheenu No Bro, I did not give access to any of the picklist values for the record type B. But the field is visible in the page layout of the record type B. My question here is, if the field F1 is visible in the page layout and record type for that page layout do not have access to any of the picklist values , will all the picklist values will be available for the users to select by default?

Comment: Bro Definitely,  every picklist fields will be available to edit for any Record Type. Atleast one  value from the picklist field should be given access for any record Type. Only way to take out the access of picklist field is either by restricting the field access to certain profile at the time of creation or by removing the picklist field from page layout and that page layout should be assigned to the record type for which you wish there should be no access.

Comment: If the picklist field is visible then atleast one value will be visible. Simple way to check is we have go to the record type and look for the picklist field name and click edit and there you could see the picklist values that are accessible.

Comment: @prasanthcheenu Thanks for the info bro. I gave access to 2 pick list values Yes and No to the record type B and now it shows only those 2 values and not N/A. But previously there was no access to any of the picklist values and it was displaying all 3 values for the user. Now I understand, if the field is visible to users and if there is no access for any of the picklist values then all the picklist values will be visible to the user. right?